# Adding a legend to a ggplot map

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to visualise map-related data. I have coloured regions according to a continuous value, and I would like to add a legend with colors and region names. My own data is a bit cumbersome to share, but I have recreated the scenario with public data ([Mapping in ggplot2](https://r-charts.com/spatial/maps-ggplot2/)). The following code creates the included map:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

# Import a geojson or shapefile
map <- read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/R-CoderDotCom/data/main/shapefile_spain/spain.geojson")

ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = unemp_rate)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 2)
```

[image: Map of Spain with regions named and coloured]

Instead of the continuous default legend, I would like to have a legend with names, numbers and colors. Basically, a legend that shows the `name` and `unemp_rate` columns of the data with colors matching the map (eg. `unemp_rate`). Somewhat like the legend of the second included picture (but the colors are not right).

| name | unemp_rate |
| --- | --- |
| "Andalucía" | 18.68 |
| "Aragón" | 8.96 |
| "Principado de Asturias" | 11.36 |
| "Islas Baleares" | 9.29 |
| "Islas Canarias" | 17.76 |
| "Cantabria" | 8.17 |
| "Castilla y León" | 10.19 |
| "Castilla-La Mancha" | 14.11 |
| "Cataluña" | 9.29 |
| "Comunidad Valenciana" | 12.81 |
| "Extremadura" | 16.73 |
| "Galicia" | 11.20 |
| "Comunidad de Madrid" | 10.18 |
| "Región de Murcia" | 12.18 |
| "Comunidad Foral de Navarra" | 8.76 |
| "País Vasco" | 8.75 |
| "La Rioja" | 10.19 |
| "Ceuta y Melilla" | 23.71 |

[image: Second picture]

My actual code looks like so:

```
ggplot(map, aes(geometry = geometry, fill = Y1)) +
  theme_bw() + geom_sf(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "brown", high = "green") +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or statistical question, please edit to clarify. However, this question looks like it would be on topic on [SO], so I will vote to migrate it there.  If you want it migrated faster, flag your Q for moderator assistance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just to clarify, would you like each country to be it's own discrete color? Or still have the gradient colors?

Comment: A would like each country's color to reflect the `unemp_rate`. Ideally each country would be coloured as `scale_fill_gradient2(low = "brown", high = "green")` would do it. It is like embedding the table into to graph and using the same colors in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an inset bar chart instead:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)
# Import a geojson or shapefile
map_ <- read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/R-CoderDotCom/data/main/shapefile_spain/spain.geojson") %>% 
  mutate(name = forcats::fct_reorder(name, desc(unemp_rate)))

g1 <- map_ %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = unemp_rate)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "brown", high = "green", midpoint = 16) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank())

g2 <- map_ %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = unemp_rate, y = name, fill = unemp_rate)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "brown", high = "green", midpoint = 16) +
  geom_text(aes(label = name, x = .5, hjust = 0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = unemp_rate), nudge_x = - .5, hjust = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

g1 + inset_element(g2, 0, .2, .9, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit involved, since this is a pretty non-standard way of making a legend, but not too bad with help from the `scales` package. You can make your own color scale first, e.g. like so:

```
library(scales)
my_pal <- seq_gradient_pal(low = 'brown', high = 'green')
my_scale <- col_numeric(palette = my_pal, domain = range(map$unemp_rate))
my_cols <- setNames(my_scale(map$unemp_rate), map$name)

ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = name)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_cols,
    name = "Unemployment rate",
    labels = setNames(paste(map$name, map$unemp_rate, sep = ': '), map$name)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good! I have used `scale_fill_gradient2(low = "brown", high = "green")` in my actual code. Can I still use it?

Comment: Thank you! Getting there, but not quite. The `scale_fill_gradient2(low = "brown", high = "green")` function has white in the middle. I'm trying to reproduce that now. If nothing else comes along I will accept this after a day. You where definitely right about this being involved. I had this great idea that I'm starting to doubt.

Comment: Sorry, read too quickly, use e.g. `div_gradient_pal` instead of `seq_gradient_pal`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a field which combines the name and unemployment rate and use that for the fill variable. Also I am not sure about the "colours are not right" part, but maybe you want a continuous colour scale? So I am using viridis colour palette to get similar continuous scale but for categorical data.

```
map |> 
    mutate(fill_var = paste0(name, ' - ', unemp_rate)) |> 
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = fill_var)) +
    geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 2) + 
    ggthemes::theme_map() + # optional
    scale_fill_viridis_d() + 
    labs(fill = "")
```

[image: sample_plot_output_with_legends]

Comment: I would like the color to reflect the `unemp_rate` value.